# onclick function not working? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So thanks to some brilliant minds I've now been able to make my image move left/right and up/down using JQuery, problem is, I need the image to move horizontally and then when the mouse is clicked, change to vertically moving up/down.  The code I was given works perfectly in JSFiddle, but not when I implement it into my file and I have no clue why.  Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Task 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task2.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="task2.js"></script>

<div id="animate">Sample</div>
</head>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#animate {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
var upleft = 0;

function goRight() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        left: width
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
    });
}

function goLeft() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        left: 0
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goRight, 50);
    });
}

function goUp() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        top: 0
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goDown, 50);
    });
}

function goDown() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        top: height
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goUp, 50);
    });
}
setTimeout(goRight, 50);

$("#animate").on('click', function () {
    $('#animate').stop();
    if (upleft == 0) {
        goDown();
        upleft = 1;
    } else {
        goLeft();
        upleft = 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you check FF firebug error console, what error you are getting there.

Comment: Can you please share the JSFiddle link?

Comment: Is code wrapped in document ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: What version of jquery are you using in your local version?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qVewK/ is JSFIDDLE link and i'm using version 1.11.1, no it isnt wrapped in a document ready, ill try that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the jQuery code with **$(document).ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // jQuery code goes here

});
```

If I'm not mistaken, JSFiddle has this by default.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
var upleft = 0;

function goRight() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        left: width
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
    });
}

function goLeft() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        left: 0
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goRight, 50);
    });
}

function goUp() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        top: 0
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goDown, 50);
    });
}

function goDown() {
    $("#animate").animate({
        top: height
    }, 5000, function () {
        setTimeout(goUp, 50);
    });
}
setTimeout(goRight, 50);

$(document).on('click', '#animate' function () {
    $('#animate').stop();
    if (upleft == 0) {
        goDown();
        upleft = 1;
    } else {
        goLeft();
        upleft = 0
    }
});
});
```